# Integrating Kafka producer and consumer inside web application

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

What is the best strategy to integrate Kafka producer and consumer inside the tomcat web application?'

I am using spring-integration-kafka latest release.

Thanks

I am not able to produce messages in when using the same code inside Spring MVC. However, it works when used in standalone Java Program.

```
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG QueueChannel:383 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inputToKafka', message: GenericMessage [payload=EventLogEvent{key=com.springapp.mvc.util.EventLogEventKey@cb5d2218, numberOfEvents=10, resetCounterInDays=5, template=6, proposition=5}, headers={timestamp=1425653206240, id=eccb00b0-6617-b5c4-6de0-45a08730041e, messageKey=1, kafka_topic=test-hs}]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:1610 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'hello'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG TestDispatcherServlet:1225 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'hello'; URL [/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG InternalResourceView:432 - Added model object 'message' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'hello'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG InternalResourceView:166 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'hello'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG MockRequestDispatcher:67 - MockRequestDispatcher: forwarding to [/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG TestDispatcherServlet:996 - Successfully completed request
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:86 - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@68af6fa0 testClass = AppTests, testInstance = com.springapp.mvc.AppTests@55c9a711, testMethod = simple@AppTests, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@70e08379 testClass = AppTests, locations = '{file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG ServletTestExecutionListener:147 - Resetting RequestContextHolder for test context [DefaultTestContext@68af6fa0 testClass = AppTests, testInstance = com.springapp.mvc.AppTests@55c9a711, testMethod = simple@AppTests, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@70e08379 testClass = AppTests, locations = '{file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:118 - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@68af6fa0 testClass = AppTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@70e08379 testClass = AppTests, locations = '{file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  GenericWebApplicationContext:862 - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@5f0dd6db: startup date [Fri Mar 06 15:46:45 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kafkaProducerContext'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor:356 - Stopping beans in phase 1073741823
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor:356 - Stopping beans in phase 0
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor:226 - Asking bean 'kafkaProducerContext' of type [class org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext] to stop
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  Producer:68 - Shutting down producer
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  ProducerPool:68 - Closing all sync producers
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor:235 - Bean 'kafkaProducerContext' completed its stop procedure
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor:226 - Asking bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  EventDrivenConsumer:83 - Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  PublishSubscribeChannel:69 - Channel 'org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@5f0dd6db.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor:235 - Bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' completed its stop procedure
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  EventDrivenConsumer:131 - stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor:356 - Stopping beans in phase -2147483648
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:499 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@53164a3b: defining beans [channelInitializer,$autoCreateChannelCandidates,IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor,integrationEvaluationContext,org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,integrationGlobalProperties,integrationHeaderChannelRegistry,globalChannelInterceptorProcessor,jsonPath,xpath,toStringFriendlyJsonNodeToStringConverter,converterRegistrar,integrationConversionService,DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,datatypeChannelMessageConverter,messageBuilderFactory,inputToKafka,org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0,kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter,taskExecutor,kafkaSpecificEncoder,producerProperties,kafkaProducerContext,helloController,kafkaProducer,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,nullChannel,errorChannel,_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger,taskScheduler,org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:555 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#220d52b8': [_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:555 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#40452b0f': [kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:245 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'taskExecutor'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:555 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#2051acec': [kafkaProducerContext]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:555 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#1d79997b': [(inner bean)#2051acec]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:555 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#1d79997b#1': [(inner bean)#7779ad44]
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:245 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'taskScheduler'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 INFO  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2015-03-06 15:46:46 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:555 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#77ce5421': [taskScheduler]
```

The same code is pasted below. Two resources are defined one is using Kafka native Java API and it is working. Other resource is using spring-integration and it is not working.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    ">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<int:channel id="inputToKafka">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                    auto-startup="false"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    order="1"


        >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

<bean id="producerProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">3600000</prop>
            <prop key="message.send.max.retries">5</prop>
            <prop key="serializer.class">kafka.serializer.StringEncoder</prop>
            <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
                            producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="172.16.1.13:9092"
                                          topic="test-hs"
                                         value-class-type="java.lang.Object"
                                          compression-codec="default"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>
```

The controller class

```
package com.springapp.mvc;
import com.springapp.mvc.util.EventLogEvent;
import com.springapp.mvc.util.EventLogEventKey;
import com.springapp.mvc.util.KafkaEventLogWriterChannel;
import com.springapp.mvc.util.KafkaProducer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class KafkaController {

@Autowired
private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");

    kafkaProducer.sendMessageToKafka();
    return "hello";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/native", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void nativeAPI(@RequestBody String bookCase) throws Exception {


    KafkaEventLogWriterChannel ch = new KafkaEventLogWriterChannel("test-hs");
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("kafka.api", "native");
    ch.writeData(data);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/spring", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void springIntegration(@RequestBody String bookCase) throws Exception     {

    kafkaProducer.sendMessageToKafka();

}
}
```

The Class which is sending message using spring-integration 1.0 API.

```
package com.springapp.mvc.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
/**
 * Created by hs on 06-03-2015.
*/
@Component
public class KafkaProducer {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("inputToKafka")
MessageChannel inputToKafka;


public void sendMessageToKafka()
{

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("kafka.api", "spring-integration");

   boolean status =  inputToKafka.send(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(data).setHeader("messageKey", String.valueOf(1)).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "test-hs").build());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, be more specific.

The Spring Integration Kafka Support is just an extension for the Spring Integration, which, in turn, is an extension of the Spring Framework.

Since you can simply implement Spring MVC Web application, there is no any stops to provide for it any other integration stuff, like Kafka.

Since Spring Integration implements EIP and provide enough adapters for well-know protocols and connects everything with `MessageChannel` and `Message` abstractions you can simply accept HTTP requests using `<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>` and send it to the `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

It may be won't be so easy to do vise versa: from Kafka to the HTTP client, but you can do that via any other adapters and protocols, like JDBC (to store Kafka messages) or WebSockets to push Kafka messages to the connected clients.

Right now I don't see any issues to provide any desired integration solutions within Web application based on the Spring portfolio.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the quick response. Do I really need to make a call to context.start() before sending the messages and similarly before consuming? I need to store the data into master directly and then post the same data onto kafka so that it can be consumed by  spark and other consumers.

Comment: Not sure what is `context.start()` in your case, but if your Web-app is based on the Spring the application context will be started together with the web-app deployment on the server. Hence any channel-adapter will be ready to receive messages from its channel and send it to the target system, like Kafka.

Comment: Thanks Artem for answering this.

Comment: I am able to send message when I am using spring-kafka in a standalone java application. However, inside web application, messages are  never getting delivered to the kafka server.

Comment: Well, you should share the code (how you send message) and maybe logs, if there is some noise on the matter.

Comment: `public class KafkaProducer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("inputToKafka")
    MessageChannel inputToKafka;

    public void sendMessageToKafka()
    {

        EventLogEventKey eventKey = new EventLogEventKey();
 
       boolean status =  inputToKafka.send(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(event).setHeader("messageKey", String.valueOf(1)).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "test-hs").build(), 100000);

    }

} `

Comment: I have added the log in the answer as there is limit in the comment section.

Comment: I compared my standalone app and spring mvc logs and found out that task-executor is not starting  when kafka-producer is integrated inside Spring MVC. What could be the reason?

Comment: How does it work without `taskExecutor`? What is the reason to use it for the `poller` at all ? From other side, looking to your logs, you try to test it from using MockMVC, but just after `send` message you go to the end of test and the application context is closed. Since you use `queue` and `taskExecutor` for message hand-off, to be sure that it is sent you should have some `CountDownLetch` or simple `Thread.sleep` in the end of test to provide some delay before context close.

Comment: I already had thread.sleep at the end and it worked after setting  auto-startup="true".  Now I am facing issues in Consuming it. I will post a separate question for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and solved by change the configuration **auto-startup** from **false** to **true**

```
auto-startup="true"
```

which in

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                auto-startup="false"
                                channel="inputToKafka"
                                order="1"


    >
```

It works!